# Laravel Validation 'starts_with' alpha

Tags: laravel, validation

I am looking to use Laravel validation for user input fields, and all works well aside from one rule I'm looking to enforce: how to ensure a field starts with alpha (where it allows alpha_dash elsewhere).  I tried the PHP 'regexp' version [A-Za-z] (shown in code snippet below) but to no avail.  I also tried 'starts_with:alpha' also to no avail.  I'm hoping to avoid regexp and the like and would rather wait for Laravel solution if there is no simple solution.

Thanks!

```
'username' => 'required|starts_with:[A-Za-z]|alpha_dash|max:20|unique:users,username',
'firstname' => 'required|starts_with:[A-Za-z]|alpha_dash|max:20',
'lastname' => 'required|starts_with:[A-Za-z]|alpha_dash|max:30',
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this rule instead of `alpha_dash` & `starts_with`:

```
'required|min:2|max:30|regex:/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/'
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Makdous.  I tried adding this to the rules like so:  'required|min:2|max:30|regex:/^[a-z|A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/' but an error "preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found".  I will search the error message and see if I can get this to work, will respond shortly.

Comment: I see the error is because the regex has a pipe in it.  I want to keep this as a string and not an array since I'm using this in a trait, and have since wanted the initial character to be a capital.  So with these constraints your rule works well when I modify it to: 'required|min:2|max:30|regex:/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/'   Thank you again!